# Json wont response my array in php

Tags: php, android, mysql, json, android-json

I am trying to fetch multiple rows from my database and then encode them with `json` so I can access them in my Android application. I've successfully encoded an object but I couldn't find a way to do the same with an array. My code looks like:

if ($tag == 'friends') {

```
    $id = $_POST['id'];

    $friends = $db->getMyFriends($id);
    if ($friends != false) {
        // friends found          
        $result[] = array();
            while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($friends)){
                $response[ "error"] = FALSE;
                $result[] = array(
                $response["friends"]["unique_id"] = $row["unique_id"],
                $response["friends"]["name"] = $row["name"],
                $response["friends"]["email"] = $row["email"]);
            }

        echo json_encode($response);
    }
```

The code from getMyFriends($id) I have already tested and it works fine. It returns :

$result = mysql_fetch_array($result);
                return $result;

When using a rest client passing the parameters:
Tag: friends
id: $id

this is the `json` response that I get:
{
    "tag": "myfriends",
    "error": false
}
, but no actual database data.

If anyone knows what I'm doing wrong, I'd really appreciate it, I've been browsing the internet for hours now.

Comment: May be echo json_encode($result); ?

Comment: You need to add `result[]` into `response[]`.

Comment: So getMyFriends is already returning a fetch_array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If getMyFriends already have a `$result = mysql_fetch_array($result);`you don't need to fetch again.

You could simply:

```
$friends = $db->getMyFriends($id);
echo json_encode($friends);
```

But that will only return one friend, if you want all remove `$result = mysql_fetch_array($result);` from getMyFriends and return the pure mysql_result, then do something like:

```
 $result = array();
 while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($friends)){
    array_push($result,$row);
 }
 echo json_encode($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it worked.

```
if($tag=='friends'){ 
$id = $_REQUEST['id'];
$friends = $db->getMyFriends($id);
if ($friends != false) {
// friends found          
$result[] = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($friends)){
    $response[ "error"] = FALSE;
    $result[] = array(
    $response["friends"]["unique_id"] = $row["id"],
    $response["friends"]["name"] = $row["name"],
    $response["friends"]["email"] = $row["email"]
    );
}

echo json_encode($result);
}
}
```

Comment: Echoing the result instead of the response returns '[[]]' in json for me.